# What is the regular expression to ensure a string is a given format?

Tags: regex

I am very unfamiliar with regular expressions, so I have no idea where to start with this. I need to store a time range value in a file. I'd like to validate that against a regular expression before saving it.

The format has to be:

```
00:00-00:00
```

where the min value of the digits can be 0 and the max values can be represented as

```
23:59-23:59
```

How can I ensure the string matches this constraint?

Comment: You could start from the [Wikipedia page on regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and proceed from there.

Comment: Regular expressions are briefly explained [here](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) OR try [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/884783.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
\b((?:(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))-(?:(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5][0-9])))\b
```

**Explanation**

```
\b                   # Assert position at a word boundary
(                    # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   (?:                  # Match the regular expression below
      (?:                  # Match the regular expression below
                              # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
            [01]                 # Match a single character present in the list “01”
            [0-9]                # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
         |                    # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
            2                    # Match the character “2” literally
            [0-3]                # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “3”
      )
      :                    # Match the character “:” literally
      (?:                  # Match the regular expression below
         [0-5]                # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5”
         [0-9]                # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
      )
   )
   -                    # Match the character “-” literally
   (?:                  # Match the regular expression below
      (?:                  # Match the regular expression below
                              # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
            [01]                 # Match a single character present in the list “01”
            [0-9]                # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
         |                    # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
            2                    # Match the character “2” literally
            [0-3]                # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “3”
      )
      :                    # Match the character “:” literally
      (?:                  # Match the regular expression below
         [0-5]                # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5”
         [0-9]                # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
      )
   )
)
\b                   # Assert position at a word boundary
```